# Add DOM event to Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I want to attach a DOM event to a directive element so as to update a scope property. Unfortunately, I can't find a "clean" way to do this. The only way I can get this to work now is to explicitly invoke `$apply()` inside the handler. This is bad practice, I know, but it also prevents me from sharing this code with native angular directives, such as with `ng-click="myDOMEventHandler()"` (because it triggers an `$apply already in progress` exception.

Is there a way to add a DOM event to a directive element so that changes to the scope are picked up, but without having to call `$apply()`?

Here is a simple example of what I mean. [You can edit this Plunker as well](http://plnkr.co/edit/gbyPjaEzWjUKtxy3EnIn?p=preview)).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.keystrokes = 0;

      var report = angular.element('<div ng-click="increment()">keystrokes: {{keystrokes}}</div>');
      element.after(report);
      $compile(report)(scope);

      scope.increment = function () {
        scope.keystrokes += 1;
        scope.$apply();
      };

      element.on('keyup', scope.increment);
    }
  };
});
```

If you enter some text in the input, the counter increments. And if you click on the button, the counter also increments -- but if raises a `$apply already in progress` exception.

If you remove the `scope.$apply()`, then the exception goes away and the scope properties do change, but these changes are never displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use scope.$apply inside scope.increment function but you should use

`$apply` inside `element.on('keyup'...))` as you binding there event outside angular scope

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.keystrokes = 0;

      var report = angular.element('<div>keystrokes and clicks: {{keystrokes}} <button ng-click="increment()">Or click me</button></div>');
      element.after(report);
      $compile(report)(scope);

      scope.increment = function () {
        scope.keystrokes += 1;
      
      };
      
      element.on('keyup', function(){
        
        scope.$apply(function(){
          
          scope.increment();
          
        });
        
        
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <input my-directive="" />
</body>
```

Comment: But is there a way to do this without putting markup into the parent document? Adding it to the `<input>` directly makes it look like an external dependency. It just feels to me like the directive itself should be able to handle this.

Comment: @Andrew in that case you can move scope.$apply scope.increment to element.on('keyup', ... because that event trigger outside angular scope and you can use $apply only here to perform scope life cycle

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does seem to be the only way to go. What a hassle, though. I think you also need to run `scope.$on('$destroy')` to cleanly remove the event listener and not have any leaks. I think this means you can't run the `scope.$apply()` inside an anonymous function, but instead you need an intermediate function, which 1) you bind `keyup` to, 2) you can bind `scope.$on('$destroy')` to, and 3) runs `scope.$apply()`. It really seems like something Angular should integrate natively because they are already doing all this in their own native directives already. But this does work!